# Passing state to more than one child component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm having trouble understanding how to pass state as props to other child components in React. In my code, you can see I've got a component that takes input and maps it to my state array, displaying part of that data in another component, that's working just fine.

But the overall goal is that when a user clicks on an item they've added to the list, React Router kicks in and changes the view to the MovieDetails component, which will have extra information they've entered, like title, date and description.

I haven't even gotten to setting up react router because I can't seem to properly access state within the MovieDetails component. And then I'm not quite sure how to display the correct MovieDetails component with router.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addMovie = this.addMovie.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      movies : []
    };
  }

  addMovie(movie) {
    let movies = this.state.movies;
    movies.push(movie);
    this.setState({ movies });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="container">
          <div>
            <h3 className="heading">Favorite Movies</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <AddMovie addMovie={ this.addMovie }/>
          <MovieList movies={ this.state.movies }/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class AddMovie extends Component {
  addMovie(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const movie = {
      title : this.title.value,
      year  : this.year.value,
      image : this.image.value,
      desc  : this.desc.value
    }
    this.props.addMovie(movie);
    this.movieForm.reset();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form ref={(input) => this.movieForm = input} onSubmit={(e) => this.addMovie(e)}>
          <input ref={(input) => this.title = input} className="Input" type="text" placeholder="Title"/>
          <input ref={(input) => this.year = input} className="Input" type="text" placeholder="Year"/>
          <textarea ref={(input) => this.desc = input} className="Input" type="text" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
          <input ref={(input) => this.image = input} className="Input" type="text" placeholder="Poster URL"/>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class MovieList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.movies.map( (movie, i) => <MovieListItem key={i} details={ movie }/> )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class MovieListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggleClass = this.toggleClass.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      active: false
    };
  }
  toggleClass() {
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({ active: !currentState });
  }
  render() {
    const { details } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        className={this.state.active ? "red": null}
        onClick={this.toggleClass}
      >
        <img src={details.image} alt=""/>
        <hr/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class MovieDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>title here</p>
        <p>year here</p>
        <p>description here</p>
        <img src="image" alt=""/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I do not really understand where is your problem. Could you try to make a snipet, or a codePen ?

Comment: Took me a minute, and it's not quite working right, but here it is on CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwLoaq?editors=0010 Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, do you want to push to a new component (where the `details` should be accessible) when you're clicking on an item created from MovieList? If so, here are the steps you have to do:

1. If you want to push a new view you have to use something like `browserHistory` or `hashHistory` from 'react-router'. In this case I'll use `browserHistory`.
2. To access the state in `MovieDetails` component simply pass it through `browserHistory`.

Here is the way I used your code to push to a new view when an item from MovieList component is clicked:

```
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from "react-router";

class Routes extends Component {
  render() {
    let props = this.props;

    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}/>
        <Route path="/movie-details" component={MovieDetails}/>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

// Here is your App component
class App extends Component {
  // ... your code
}

// ... your other classes


class MovieListItem extends Component {
  // ... Constructor 
  // Here I'm pushing the new route for MovieDetails view
  toggleClass(details) {
    browserHistory.push({
      pathname: '/movie-details',
      state: details // pass the state to MovieDetails
    });
    // ... your code
  }

  render() {
    const {details} = this.props;

    return (
      <div
       // ... your code
       onClick={this.toggleClass.bind(this, details)} // pass details to toggleClass() 
      >
      // ... your code
      </div>
    )
  }
}    

// Here is your Movie Details component
class MovieDetails extends Component { 
  console.log('This props: ', this.props.location.state); // The details object should be logged here
  // ... your code
}

// Export Routes instead of App
export default Routes;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hmm... I see where you're going, but I tried it out and now it's only loading 
up the MovieDetails component with my test content displaying on the page. And I can't force it to go to the home page--it keeps loading the path for MovieDetails.

And I still get an error when trying to access MovieListItem data in MovieDetails.

Comment: Again, are you sure I got your flow right? Here is a [.gif](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfsx364cer6kse5/20170624_192319.gif?dl=0) where you can see the flow and the props received in `MovieDetails` component. I edited my code so the `toggleClass` is binded from the click event. Also, i logged the hole path to the state that should be received into `MovieDetails` component.

Comment: Oh! Wow. It works. Okay, I got it working using `match.params` and grabbed the id, assigned that to a variable and passed it in as the array index of my state.

Comment: Glad to hear that works. If you want to have a good management of the state of each component, my advice for you is use redux, where you can keep every single piece of data, to maintain a controlled version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from the way you try to access the input values. When you use `ref`, you get a React wrapper, not the real DOM element, so you can't access directly to `.value` or `.reset()`. You have to use the `getDOMNode()` method to get the DOM element. This worked for me :

```
const movie = {
  title : this.title.getDOMNode().value,
  year  : this.year.getDOMNode().value,
  image : this.image.getDOMNode().value,
  desc  : this.desc.getDOMNode().value
};

...

this.movieForm.getDOMNode().reset();
```

An other thing, when you `setState` something that uses the current state, you should use the callback instead :

```
addMovie(newMovie) {
  this.setState(({movies: prevMovies})=> ({
    movies: [...prevMovies, newMovie]
  }));
}
```

See complete `setState` API from [official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: Thanks! Okay, I seem to be able to access data in the array inside the MovieDetails component if I use the array index. Now I'm trying to figure out how to use router to display the MovieDetails component with the corresponding data from the movie list item a user clicks.

Comment: See the official doc, it's pretty clear. Just plug your component with the correct route like `<Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/add" component={AddMovie}/>
        <Route path="/list" component={MovieList}/>
      </Router>`